# set buttons at specific positions in android

Tags: android, android-layout

I want to place a button on image view at specific position.i.e at fixed x,y position. Is it possible to do that since android have different screen size for every device.

I have tried doing that using layout params but its not working properly.

```
POI3 = new Button(this);
    POI3.setId(3);
    POI3.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
    POI3.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            onButtonClick("3");
        }
    });
    params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(75, 75);
    params.leftMargin = 466;
    params.topMargin = 255;

    // This line defines how params.leftMargin and params.topMargin are interpreted.
    // In this case, "<80,90>" means <80,90> to the right of the yellow ImageView.
    params.addRule(RelativeLayout.RIGHT_OF, yellow_iv_id);

    rl.addView(POI3, params);
```

Comment: "its not working properly" Care to elaborate?

Comment: provide line of code where do you init yellow_iv_id.

Comment: "its not working properly" means the click event is not getting at that exact position.

Comment: But, why are  you adding buttons dynamically. you can design in xml and that foe every screen size.

Comment: Use Point to add view at specific positions

Comment: @Sharmilee ...i have an image with some points on it and on that points i want to fire a click event.So i was trying to place a transparent button on those points.and handle click event.

Comment: @Droid...can u give me an example please..

Comment: You can set the button at top,bottom,right,left,centre vertical, centre horizontal etc w.r.t imageview and also give padding in the image view. In this way the button will remain in fix position in different layouts.

Answer (score 0):

for set your button in fix position you must use `dp` instead of `xp`,use following code to convert that:

```
    /**
    * This method converts dp unit to equivalent pixels, depending on device density. 
    * 
    * @param dp A value in dp (density independent pixels) unit. Which we need to        convert into pixels
    * @param context Context to get resources and device specific display metrics
   * @return A float value to represent px equivalent to dp depending on device density
   */
    public static float convertDpToPixel(float dp, Context context){
    Resources resources = context.getResources();
    DisplayMetrics metrics = resources.getDisplayMetrics();
    float px = dp * (metrics.densityDpi / 160f);
    return px;
  }

 /**
 * This method converts device specific pixels to density independent pixels.
 * 
 * @param px A value in px (pixels) unit. Which we need to convert into db
 * @param context Context to get resources and device specific display metrics
 * @return A float value to represent dp equivalent to px value
  */
public static float convertPixelsToDp(float px, Context context){
    Resources resources = context.getResources();
    DisplayMetrics metrics = resources.getDisplayMetrics();
    float dp = px / (metrics.densityDpi / 160f);
    return dp;
}
```